# jQuery DataTables multiple select column filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

What I would like to get is excel-like multiple criteria filtering for individual DataTables columns. I have come across few topics here on stackoverflow related to the subject but none of those seem to implement what I'm looking for.

So far, I've got only sample table and I'd appreciate any (even most high-level) guidance as of where to move next.

```js
 var tableData = [
  {name: 'Clark Kent', city: 'Metropolis'},
   {name: 'Bruce Wayne', city: 'Gotham'},
   {name: 'Steve Rogers', city: 'New York'},
   {name: 'Peter Parker', city: 'New York'},
   {name: 'Thor Odinson', city: 'Asgard'}
 ];

 var dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
   data: tableData,
   columns: [
  {data: 'name', title: 'Name'},
  {data: 'city', title: 'City'}
   ]
 });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should define "excel-like multiple criteria filtering for individual DataTables columns" as it applies to your dataset (by itself, it is sounds like a pretty massive step from "I've got only sample table".......)  I believe I have an idea of what you are trying to go for, but to write all the code for you - ain't gonna happen.... - you are just too far off.  Show what you have tried, details of where you want to go, etc. and you can get help.  Posting 'sample data' and asking for the 'world' won't get very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find of use following  [DataTables plug-in](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter). I have somewhat extended your example for demonstration purposes (it works somewhat slow as non-minified files served from github through jsdelivr):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 //Source data definition 
 var tableData = [{
   name: 'Clark Kent',
   city: 'Metropolis',
   race: 'cryptonian'
  }, {
   name: 'Bruce Wayne',
   city: 'Gotham',
   race: 'human'
  }, {
   name: 'Steve Rogers',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }, {
   name: 'Peter Parker',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }, {
   name: 'Thor Odinson',
   city: 'Asgard',
   race: 'god'
  }, {
   name: 'Jonathan Osterman',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }, {
   name: 'Walter Kovacs',
   city: 'New Jersey',
   race: 'human'
  }, {
   name: 'Arthur Curry',
   city: 'Atlantis',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }, {
   name: 'Tony Stark',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'human'
  }, {
   name: 'Scott Lang',
   city: 'Coral Gables',
   race: 'human'
  }, {
   name: 'Bruce Banner',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }
 ];
 //DataTable definition 
 window.dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
   sDom: 'tF',
   data: tableData,
   columns: [{
     data: 'name',
     title: 'Name'
    }, {
     data: 'city',
     title: 'City'
    }, {
     data: 'race',
     title: 'Race'
  
   }]
 });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/js/mfilter.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/css/mfilter.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```